# Can a neutron star compress until it's converted to a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, neutron-stars

The Universe's densest objects are black holes. In the second place, there are neutron stars.

So, if a neutron star compresses to its Schwarzschild radius, would it appear as a black hole? That black hole would be one of the most dense objects in the universe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, before you got to the Schwarzschild radius, the pressure previously supporting the neutron star against its own gravity would no longer be able to do so, and the entire star would violently collapse. Some matter would be thrown out, while the rest would become a black hole. The singularity at the center would be among all the rest of the singularities at the centers of all other black holes for the densest objects in the Universe.

Comment: Consider a "stable" neutron star. Are there any mechanisms that allow it to slowly compress further, until it's enough to implode into a singularity? Would mere cooling do that?

Comment: @FlorinAndrei Neutron stars are supported by degenerate neutron pressure. Converting neutrons into strange hadrons would reduce the neutron density, but if that mechanism is energetically favorable you get a soft equation of state and consequently a low maximum mass which increasingly looks ruled out by the data.

Comment: So, that seems to indicate that, if they don't collapse into a black hole at first, chances are won't collapse later on, is that right?

Comment: Unless there is an external source of mass...as is the case in some binary systems that include neutron stars. Mass loss from the companion accumulates on the neutron star until ***BOOM*** you get a type uhm...one? supernova.

Comment: Hmmm... There's a thought. Type Ia supernova occur when a carbon-oxygen white-dwarf gains enough mass to start fusing carbon into heavier elements. I'm not sure if a parallel exists for accreting neutron stars or, if not, why not. Perhaps time for a new question...

Comment: is it a coincidence that degeneracy pressure of neutron stars is enough to keep it outside the Schwarzschild radius?

Comment: @Jus12 The degeneracy pressure of neutrons inside typical neutron stars is not sufficient to keep them outside their Schwarzschild radii. There is also of course an observational selection effect. You cannot see a neutron star that has disappeared inside its Schwarzschild radius.

Comment: related: depending on how much the NS is close to a BH, the CMB will be blue shifted, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/623841/226902

Answer (score 10):

An important point to make is that it is not possible for a neutron star to shrink "gradually" so that it disappears quietly inside its own event horizon. There will always be some sort of violent collapse because a neutron star becomes unstable at radii significantly larger than the Schwarzschild radius.

A neutron star which gains mass could shrink. This is because the equation of state is temperature independent and may have a density dependence such that the mass-radius relation results in more massive neutron stars being smaller. (This is definitely true for ideal neutron degeneracy pressure, but the equation of state in a neutron star is *far* more complicated than that - a neutron star supported only by neutron degeneracy pressure could never exceed $0.7M_{\odot}$, the *original* TOV limit!)

However, there are limits imposed by causality and General Relativity on the structure of neutron stars. In "Black Holes, White Dwarfs and Neutron Stars" by Shapiro & Teukolsky, (pp.260-261), it is shown, approximately, that even if the equation of state hardens to the point where the speed of sound equals the speed of light, that $(GM/Rc^2)<0.405$.

The Schwarzschild radius is $R_s=2GM/c^2$ and therefore $R > 1.23 R_s$ for stability. This limit is reached for a neutron star with $M \simeq 3.5 M_{\odot}$.
A more accurate treatment in [Lattimer (2013)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.3510) suggests that a maximally compact neutron star has $R\geq 1.41R_s$.

If the equation of state is softer, then collapse will occur at smaller masses, and higher densities but at a similar multiple of $R_s$.

Thus there will always be some sort of violent collapse event associated with accretion onto a neutron star that then exceeds the TOV limit.

The picture below (from [Demorest et al. 2010](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010Natur.467.1081D)) shows the mass-radius relations for a wide variety of equations of state. The limits in the top-left of the diagram indicate the limits imposed by (most stringently) the speed of sound being the speed of light (labelled "causality" and which gives radii slightly larger than Shapiro & Teukolsky's approximate result) and then in the very top left, the border marked by "GR" coincides with the Schwarzschild radius. Real neutron stars become unstable where their mass-radius curves peak, so their radii are always significantly greater than $R_s$ at all masses.

[image: Neutron star mass-radius relations]

Comment: This is Really interesting! Thanks for adding this

Comment: Really nice answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add a little (especially to @dmckee's comment to @Florin_Andrei's response):

A typical, isolated neutron star stably resists gravity with neutron degeneracy pressure.  If instead it is accreting mass from a binary companion, it may grow beyond the [Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkoff Limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_limit) (just like the Schwarzschild limit for white-dwarfs, except for neutron stars), at which point it will inevitably succumb to gravity and collapse.

Neutron-star collapse is believed to almost always form a black-hole remnant; the exact details are unknown, but there are numerous quite successful models.  What exactly it would look like is unclear, but the emission would be much less than the supernova of a typical massive star, or white dwarf.  The observational signature would be entirely unlike a type Ia, and most likely unlike a type II as-well.

Comment: Type II supernovae are from the collapse of the cores of massive stars, and have to work their way out from the heavy blanket of material above the core. So yeah, a neutron star collapse will look entirely different than that.

Comment: The TOV limit if "A typical, isolated neutron star stably resists gravity with neutron degeneracy pressure" would be 0.7 solar masses. The strong nuclear force *is* required to harden the ideal neutron degeneracy pressure.